# how can i connect two armature bones at the root?

Tags: armature

I can extrude a bone from the root of another - however in pose mode they come apart. How and can I connect two armature bones at the root?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking how to have 2 Armature bones with the SAME root---

OBJECT MODE>SHIFT+A - Add Armature

EDIT MODE> RMB Desired Root> E (to Extrude)

[image]

RESELECT THAT ROOT and Extrude Again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can "connect" the root (B) of the second chain to the root (A) of the first chain setting the "parent" of B root bone to A root bone.

Select B root bone, in armature edit mode, then goto the "bone" panel, under "relations" and click in the textbox just under the label "parent", with a small bone icon: a list of all the armature bones will expand: select the A root bone.

From now on, in pose mode, if you move the A root bone, the other chain will follow, but you can pose both chains.